# STFT normalization

Tags: stft, scipy, window, normalization, scaling

In [Scipy's implementation of STFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html), an argument allows to scale the result as a `spectrum` or as a `psd` :

```py
if scaling == 'psd':     
    scale = 1.0 / (fs * (win*win).sum())
elif scaling == 'spectrum':
    scale = 1.0 / win.sum()**2
```

However, I haven't found a mathematical derivation of these two normalizations. I suspect that they account for the loss of energy due to windowing, but any link with a proof would help me understand.

Comment: Check out [Heinzel's publication](https://holometer.fnal.gov/GH_FFT.pdf) (sections 8 and 9 to start with)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen this paper : the same normalizations appears, but they are defined and not derived... After eq. (23) there is a paragraph about the second scaling, but I can't see what allows us to say that a "correct" way of scaling is by dividing by the sum of the window points

Comment: I see why a factor N appears with a rectangular window, but why it translates to the sum of window points with another types of windows ?

Comment: The sum of window points for a rectangular window **is** $N$

Comment: Yes, my question is more why this sum shows up ? For a rectangular window, I see the math behind, but how can i derive that with other windows ?

Comment: I see. If you want to go back to the beginnings then Harris paper *On the Use of Windows for Harmonic Analysis with the Discrete Fourier Transform* will be of interest to you (coherent & incoherent gain). If I find time I will write a proper answer.

Comment: Ok, i'll read that ! Thanks !